# PYTHON: How to access class object's members if the object is a key in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary, oop

I have the following class:

```
class car_class(object):
    def __init__(self, mileage=11, tyre_size=11):
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.tyre_size = tyre_size
        self.default_val = ''
        
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.mileage, self.tyre_size))

    def __getitem__(self, default_val):
        return self.default_val

    def __setitem__(self, default_val, mileage, tyre_size):
          self[default_val] = str(mileage) + '_' + str(tyre_size)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (self.mileage, self.tyre_size) == (other.mileage, other.tyre_size)

    def __str__(self):
    return ('dict_cl: (tyre_size=\'%d\', mileage=\'%d\'' % (int(self.tyre_size), int(self.mileage)))

def __repr__(self):
    return ('dict_cl: (tyre_size=\'%d\', mileage=\'%d\'' % (int(self.tyre_size), int(self.mileage)))

    def __ne__(self, other):
        # Not strictly necessary, but to avoid having both x==y and x!=y
        # True at the same time
        return not(self == other)
```

I also have a dictionary which takes the object of this class as the Key against a value as follows-

```
my_dict = dict()
dict_value_list = list()
mm_dict_cl = car_class()
mm_dict_cl.mileage = 29
mm_dict_cl.tyre_size = 265
dict_value_list.extend(['car_color'])
my_dict.update(mm_dict_cl = dict_value_list)
```

So the dictionary(my_dict)key has the class object(mm_dict_cl) as key and car_color as a value for this key. The Key is the class object itself having two attributes mileage and tyre_size.

Now when I print the following value of the dictionary I get the value as car_color as expected -

```
`>>>` print(my_dict[next(iter(my_dict))])
['car_color']
```

However I'm struggling to find a way to retrieve the properties of the class object.

```
>>>` print(next(iter(my_dict)))

mm_dict_cl
```

It prints the class name and the key type if printed as string.

```
`>>>` print(type(next(iter(my_dict))))

<type 'str'>
```

*Query: How can then I access the object attributes of the key?
**I want to check what is the value of tyre_size and mileage for a particular 'car_color' using the key of the dictionary **my_dict****
Please help, a novice here, trying to learn this language.*

-edit: Fixed the extend call to the list for adding 'car_colour' as a list instead of a string as pointed by SorousH Bakhtiary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you stored the **name** of the instance of your class as key in your dictionary("it is string"), so you have no control over the instance but because your object is defined in global namespace, you can retrieve it like this : (I simplified your class for the moment)

```
class car_class:
    def __init__(self, mileage=11, tyre_size=11):
        self.mileage = mileage
        self.tyre_size = tyre_size
        self.default_val = ''


my_dict = {}
dict_value_list = []
mm_dict_cl = car_class()
dict_value_list.append('car_color')
print(dict_value_list)

mm_dict_cl.mileage = 'temp1'
mm_dict_cl.tyre_size = 'temp2'
my_dict.update(mm_dict_cl=dict_value_list)

# here :
obj = globals().get(next(iter(my_dict)))
print(obj.mileage)    # prints temp1
print(obj.tyre_size)  # prints temp2
```

btw, you should have used `append` instead of `extend` method to add `'car_color'`

Comment: Thanks for the info. But how do you suggest I store the instance of the class as key and not the not the name of the instance as string itself?

Comment: @ThatDude Classes are hashable initially. When you implement `__eq__` method, then they become unhashable so you have to implement `__hash__` as well. In your case you have done that. so just : `my_dict[mm_dict_cl] = dict_value_list`. Do not use `update` with named argument.